# Is the convex cone of sums of self tensor products of vectors in a given vector space full-dimensional in the space of symmetric matrices?

Tags: vector-spaces, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, convex-geometry, convex-cone

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space. Let $S_n(V)$ denote the real vector space of all symmetric $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $V$.

Consider the convex cone $C\subset S_n(V) $ generated by taking sums of $v \otimes w := v w^T$, where $v$ and $w$ are column vectors in $V^n$.

Is this convex cone full-dimensional? That is, is every matrix in $S_n(V) $ a linear combination of matrices in $C$?

Comment: iirc if you take a basis of orthonormal  eigenvectors $v_i$ and $\lambda_i$ the evals you should have $M=\sum_i \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$

Comment: This holds true for all matrix, not only for the symmetric ones, due to SVD Decomposition.

Comment: For the Calvin answer, since $v$ and $w$ can be taken differently, you could take $v_i$ or $-v_i$ as $w_i$ to fix the sign of $\lambda_i$, which is eventually negative.

Comment: my matrices are not over the real numbers, but over $V$, a finite-dimensional real vector space.